# How to apply relevant theme based on device's theme in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, themes, darkmode

I want to add dark mode on my app and I want to implement it in a specific way: I want to "read" the device's theme and when the user is starting the app, the app should apply the device's theme. So, if my device is on dark mode, when I open the app I want to be on dark mode and use the appropriate colours I have on Assets. On the other hand, if my device is on light mode, the app should be on light mode, as well.

Do you know how to implement this feature?

Comment: Put your colours in your asset catalog, add light and dark variants. Job done.

Comment: @Paulw11 - can you answer the question to accept it ?